# Do iPhone's have a unique code that identifies them?

Tags: iphone

Do iPhone's have a unique code that identifies them? Can this be accessed via Cocoa? Something like a serial number that is unique?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Every iPhone has an UID number. You can get it by calling:

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] uniqueIdentifier]
```

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at the [UIDevice Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html).

Answer (score 0):

Another method to get your iPhone's UDID (beside by program) is to connect your device to itunes and at the "summary" page click the "serial number" row, it will show the UDID of your device (and Cellular Data Number, IMEI, etc consequently),